# Remember choice for current location for smartphone

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, geolocation, gps

I want to log a user position based on there GPS coordinates from their smartphone.

Easy, use a website. I currently have this working but its slightly annoying that when user access the info they are bothered with the alert(is it ok to use your position). I would love a method for the user to select remember this decision. Though in not confident in this capability.

Any ideas or solution are welcome!

Comment: afaik that's up to the browser to remember, not you.

Comment: Remebering the choice is not a common feature on mobile browser though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is no way for you to do this. Permissions for geolocation are handled by the browser itself.

From the [geolocation API](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/):

> 4.1 Privacy considerations for implementers of the Geolocation API
>
> User agents must not send location information to Web sites without the express permission of the user. **User agents must acquire permission through a user interface, unless they have prearranged trust relationships with users**, as described below. The user interface must include the host component of the document's URI. Those permissions that are acquired through the user interface and that are preserved beyond the current browsing session (i.e. beyond the time when the browsing context is navigated to another URL) must be revocable and user agents must respect revoked permissions.
>
> Some user agents will have prearranged trust relationships that do not require such user interfaces. For example, while a Web browser will present a user interface when a Web site performs a geolocation request, a VOIP telephone may not present any user interface when using location information to perform an E911 function.

It is the user agent's job to acquire permissions and remember those permissions.

Comment: so without modifying/creating my own browser this is a no go?

Comment: That's what it seems to imply. If it's the user agent's job to get permissions, that means the user agent needs to establish that trust relationship ("remember my choice") too. Not the web developer.